# MYSQL Date Query >=1

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is a simplified version of the dataset.

The first table is named impressions.

```
ID timestamp  user_id
 1.  6/28/2019  A
 2.  6/28/2019  B
 3.  6/28/2019  E
 4.  6/29/2019  F
 5.  6/29/2019  B
```

The second table is visits.

```
Userid Timestamp Location
A       6/28/2019  S
A       6/29/2019  C
G       6/20/2019  H
B       6/29/2019  I
A       6/30/2020  S
```

In the actual data set Location is an address which is removed for obvious reasons.

I have the part where I create a temporary table, I believe this part is correct:

```
Select impression.id, impression.timestamp, visit.timestamp, visit.location
From impression
Inner join visit on impression.user_id=visit.userid;
```

After that I am attempting a date comparison query because I need the date of Visit (data set 2) timestamp to be at least 1 day or more after the Impression (data set 1) timestamp.

I’ve tried using date diff but that’s not giving me what I want.

Comment: `visit.timestamp >= DATE_ADD(impression.timestamp, INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

Comment: Show what you tried. `DATEDIFF(impression.timestamp, visit.timestamp) >= 1` should also work.

Comment: Thanks for the help! English isn’t my first language so I’m trying to make sure I’m as clear as possible. I’ll try the date diff one as well. :)

Comment: You still need to show what you tried that didn't work.

Comment: @Strawberry I provided an example in the question so I’m confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
Select i.id, i.timestamp, v.timestamp, v.location
From impression i Inner join
     visit v
     on v.userid = i.user_id and
        v.timestamp > i.timestamp + interval 1 day;
```